# PHP `preg_match` does not seem to work on strings containing CR

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to preg match the following:

```
Aanvaller Flugel25
[1:260:7]
```

at first was like:

```
Aanvaller Flugel25 [1:260:7]
```

this preg_match doesn't work any more:

```
preg_match('#(Aanvaller|Verdediger) (.*) \[([0-9]:[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,2})\]#i', $this->_source)
```

it looks like the enter is screwing things up. The first line has an image betweem `flugel25` and `[1:260:7]` and is not copied to the textbox where my `preg_match` check it, is there a way to check for the weird enter involved?

Comment: not working anymore ??? is it dead now ? please add relevant title

Comment: [`.` does not match line breaks by default.](http://php.net/regexp.reference.dot)

Comment: well it just to match the above text (The second one) But now with the enter involved it doenst match anything anymore (So no results are returned)

Comment: @Gumbo I cant really work that in the above preg_match can you?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\s` instead of space character like this:

```
#(Aanvaller|Verdediger)\s+(.*?)\s+\[([0-9]:[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,2})\]#i
```